# When the app is terminated or notRunning, Is there any call back when the app is updated from AppStore in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This is possible on Andriod. I wonder if it is possible on iOS. I have explored it, found no information. If you have any source/information, please direct me.

Thanks.

Comment: What you want to do on update?

Comment: https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren

Comment: @aBilal17 Planning to send a push notification to the users who are running on the older versions, for that I need to know who is running on the latest version. So trying to see If there is any callback when the app is updated from AppStore even when the app is terminated or notRunning, so that I can have the exact information. If the user opens the app, I have everything setup to send the current app version number to the server.

Comment: @iParesh Thanks, but my use case is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, There is no notification triggered when an app is updated from the store, whether your app is running or not.

Previously I have stored a property in UserDefaults of the current version running and each time the app starts or is opened I check to see if the actual version is different from my last known in UserDefaults. Then if needed run any migrations or whatever are needed.